# openshift custom domain redirects to https version

Tags: .htaccess, dns, openshift

I have recently started using openshift and created a new php app which is running fine at `http://app-namespace.rhcloud.com/` and i have even added a custom domain/alias using web console `mydomain.com` and set cname record as following...

```
Name / Host / Alias : *
TTL: 300
Type: CNAME
Data / Value / Answer / Destination: app-namespace.rhcloud.com
```

When i try to run mydomain.com, it redirects to `https://www.mydomain.com/app` (https version with app subdirectory). I don't know why this is happening...

Please find dnsinfo...

```
Your www.mydomain.com A record is:
www.mydomain.com -> app-namespace.rhcloud.com -> ex-std-node450.prod.rhcloud.com -> ec2-54-242-159-72.compute-1.amazonaws.com -> [ 54.242.159.72  ]
```

Please help with this, thanks

Comment: Same problem, triple-checked CNAME, alias...

Answer (score 2):

### Double check the spelling

List the aliases with:

```
rhc alias list -a appName
```

Check the domain:

```
curl -v www.domain.co.uk
```

Usually that redirect means that you did not add the alias correctly to your openshift application.  Double check the spelling and make sure that you added the correct domain.